# Как сделать запись в Postgresql с помощью activerecord-sinatra

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, sinatra

Как сделать запись в Postgresql с помощью activerecord-sinatra. Я установил PostgreSQL, после

1 - установил gem pg - gem install pg

2 - установил gems: 
gem install activerecord
gem install sinatra-activerecord
gem install rake # to apply migrations

3 - создал подключение к бд в файле app.rb

```
# app.rb 
configure :development do set :database, {adapter: "postgresql",  encoding: "unicode", database: "your_database_name", pool: 2, username: "your_username", password: "your_password"}
end

configure :production do
  set :database, {adapter: "postgresql",  encoding: "unicode", database: "your_database_name", pool: 2, username: "your_username", password: "your_password"}
end
```

4 - Создал модель в файле app.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

5 - Задал миграцию в Rakefile файле

```
require 'sinatra/activerecord'
require 'sinatra/activerecord/rake'
require './app'
```

6 - Затем создал миграцию командой в консоле

```
rake db:create_migration NAME=create_articles
```

7 - В новом созданном файле миграции

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :articles do |t|
          t.string :title
          t.string :content
          t.boolean :published, :default => false
          t.datetime :published_on, :required => false
          t.integer :likes, :default => 0
          t.timestamps null: false
        end
      end
    end
```

8 - Выполнил команды в консоле rake db:create и rake db:migration

База данных создалась, в консоле psql отображается, а как сейчас в нее сделать запись в sinatra?

Answer (score 0):

Для создания новой записи Article:

```
Article.create(title: your_title, content: your_content, published: true, published_on: Time.now)
```

Для поиска Article по id:

```
Article.find(id)
```

Для обновления article:

```
 article = Article.find(id)
article.update(title: your_title, content: your_content, published: true, published_on: Time.now)
```

For delete article record:
Для удаления Article записи:

```
article = Article.find(id)
article.destroy
```

AR documentation:

1. https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord/ActiveRecord/Persistence
2. https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods
3. https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods